# "No code signing identities found" error building cordova app for iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, provisioning-profile

I am trying to build a cordova app for iOS here on my Mac, and I am plagued by the "No codesigning identities found" error.  Based on other posts, the frequent resolutions include stopping and restarting Xcode and rebooting, and redownloading the provisioning profile.  None of that has worked for me.

It is odd because I reference the provisioning profile by GUID in my build.json, but the error mentions the profile by name.  This indicates to me that something somewhere is successfully locating the profile.  So I am not sure why it isn't able to use it.

I get the error when I build at the command line using:

> cordova build ios --device --buildConfig="build.json"

I would think I should be able to reproduce the issue by building in Xcode, but when I load the cordova project in Xcode and build it, it seems to be fine.  But perhaps I am not doing the equivalent step in Xcode.  I am just choosing to "Build" in Xcode.  Perhaps there is another way to do the equivalent in Xcode?

This same codebase does build successfully on our build box, so this is undoubtedly a config issue here on my Mac.  What do I need to do besides download and install the provisioning profile?  I have done this both by downloading from Apple Developer and by directly installing through the Xcode preferences.

Below is the exact error I am getting:

> Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“[the name of our profile]”) were found.

I am a relative novice building an app developed by someone else.  I have tried everything near the top of the Google search results for this error, but not much else.  I am likely missing something obvious.  Pointers and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you tried locating the provisional profile in finder first and deleting it manually before reinstalling new profile? Many a times, system reboots worked for me after new provision installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not installed the Enterprise distribution certificate with the private key here on my Mac.  Once I did that it worked.